# React SetState from false to true of a specific element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a method called `handleRetry` which picks an item that i select.

This is the code

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

<Button onClick={() => handleRetry(file.temp_id)}>Retry</Button>

const handleRetry = (temp_id, error) => {
    const droppedFileError = files.find((file) => file.temp_id === temp_id);
    console.log(droppedFileError)
}
```

This is my console.log of the `droppedFileError`, as you can see the `error` is set to `true`

[image]

How can i set this `droppedFileError` to `false` in the same `handleRetry` method?

Comment: What is `file` and `files`? These aren't currently defined in the example

Comment: const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

Comment: Add your code to your question, please.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to set `error` manually, but may you try `droppedFileError.error = false`? Or would you like to update state. The question isn't clear at the moment.

Comment: It is not really clear what the `state` has to do with your question: you mention it in the title but then your question and code refer to a function that does not set the `state` anywhere (there is no call to `setFile()`). By the way, you also never use the `error` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
const handleRetry = (temp_id, error) => {
  const newFiles = files.map((file) =>
    file.temp_id === temp_id ? { ...file, error: !file.error } : file
  );
  console.log(newFiles);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Easiest way to achieve this is set error property to false.

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
                
<Button onClick={() => handleRetry(file.temp_id)}>Retry</Button>
                
const handleRetry = (temp_id, error) => {
  let droppedFileError = files.find((file) => file.temp_id === temp_id);
  droppedFileError.error = false;
  console.log(droppedFileError)
}
```